# what is the '.idea' directory in my django project folder?

Tags: django

Just curious.

It contains things like:

`encodings.xml misc.xml    modules.xml smigle.iml  vcs.xml     workspace.xml`

Comment: At a guess, it's a file created by the PyCharm IDE, which is based on IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 12):

That folder contains the project files for the JetBrains [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) Python IDE. If you use the IDE or Intellij IDEA, you should keep the folder. If you don't, it is safe to delete it.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why I never saw it until I started using PyCharm

Answer (score 1):

I had that same question. I think this [article](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207097529-What-is-the-idea-folder-) would be useful.

In resume the .idea folder contains the settings that you configured at the start of the project, and it's version control.
For example if I'm using Pycharm  one of the most common settings is the project interpreter, the .idea folder stores the settings of that interpreter, and it is useful when I'm using virtual environments.

It is totally safe to delete, but it could be useful to keep in some cases.